# Format text with HTML markup, and remove unwanted text from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am busy creating a CSV export of data, and some of the data fields contain HTML markup.

I am having some difficulties stripping all HTML tags and some text from the values/data fields passed to my method, and creating the correct output.

**This is the an example of the value/string that gets passed to my method for removing the HTML tags:**

```
"<a href=\"https://twitter.com/FNBSA\" target=\"_blank\">FNBSA</a>"
```

**This is the desired output (creating a clickable field in excel that will take you to the hyperlink address):**

```
=HYPERLINK("https://twitter.com/FNBSA","View Media")
```

You will notice, I would also like to remove the text between `_blank\">` and the closing `</a>"`, in this example, the **2nd** **FNBSA**. This value could be anything.

I have tried various different formatting, but cannot seem to get it right.

**This is currently what I have in terms of my method for removing the HTML tags and unwanted text:**

```js
str = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/FNBSA\" target=\"_blank\">FNBSA</a>";

var rem1 = str.replace('<a href=\"', '');
var rem2 = rem1.replace('\"target=\"_blank\">', '');
var rem3 = rem2.replace('</a>', '');

var value = '=HYPERLINK("' + rem3 + '","View Media")';

console.log(value)
```

Comment: Create snippet for a [mcve]

Comment: Try Regex; check my answer for example (Although it can be improved; but it will give you a base.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the hrefs are always the first attribute, try this

```js
str = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/FNBSA\" target=\"_blank\">FNBSA</a>";

var parts = str.split('\"');
var value = '=HYPERLINK("' + parts[1] + '","View Media")';

console.log(value)
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple... :D Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add space

```
var rem2 = rem1.replace('\"target=\"_blank\">', '');
```

To

```
var rem2 = rem1.replace('\" target=\"_blank\">', '');
```

```js
str = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/FNBSA\" target=\"_blank\">FNBSA</a>";

var rem1 = str.replace('<a href=\"', '');
var rem2 = rem1.replace('\" target=\"_blank\">', '');
var rem3 = rem2.replace('</a>', '');

var value = '=HYPERLINK("' + rem3 + '","View Media")';

console.log(value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it does help, but did not solve the unwanted text part :).

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex

```
str.match('http(s)?:\/\/[a-z0-9.-]+[^"\']*')[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!